# Glide Transition (withCrossFade) when using SimpleTarget

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a requirement to scale the image based on the current screen orientation. If the screen is LANDSCAPE and the image is LANDSCAPE then scale it to FIT_XY. Otherwise, if the image is PORTRAIT then scale it to FIT_CENTER. And vice versa for PORTRAIT screen orientation.

Here what I did so far:

```
 Glide.with(getContext())
      .asBitmap()
      .load(displayedImageFile)
      .transition(BitmapTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(1000))
      .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>()
      {
          @Override
          public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition)
          {
              int imgOrt = (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight()) ? Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE : Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
              switch (screenOrientation)
              {
                  case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
                      if (imgOrt == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                          imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                      else
                          imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                      break;
                  case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                      if (imgOrt == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                          imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                      else
                          imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                      break;
              }
              imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
          }
      });
```

Any idea why `withCrossFade()` doesn't work? I am a newbie with Glide. In fact, just started with Glide yesterday. I apologize if it is something simple, but I can't workout what is wrong with my code.

The only thing that I suspect is that the animation doesn't work when I am using `imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`? Any idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Try this https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-custom-animations-with-animate

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem, solved it in the following way, using Glide 4.8.0 (oh and with Kotlin, easily translateable to java):

```
Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(Uri.fromFile(bitmapFile))
            .transition(BitmapTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .apply(RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).centerCrop())
            .into(object: CustomViewTarget<ImageView, Bitmap>(imageView) {
                override fun onLoadFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {}
                override fun onResourceCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder)
                }
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                    transition?.let {
                        val didSucceedTransition = transition.transition(resource, BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView))
                        if(!didSucceedTransition) imageView.setImageBitmap(resource)
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, I will not be on my development computer until later this evening. Just a quick glance of your code, it looks like just do centerCrop for *both* orientation? Will it *stretch (FIT_XY)* when it is **landscape** and *fit center* when it is **portrait**?

Comment: I believe it will be center crop in both cases, if your landscape view is much wider then the image will be zoomed in a little bit, but maintain it's aspect ratio.

Comment: Hi Sean, unfortunately, I need it to stretch to fit the screen (on *landscape*) and on portrait to fit center.

Comment: Don't know if this is the correct way of doing it but I would just call the load function again with a different scaletype on rotate, using the cached image or landscape sized image.